# Odoo logged user data dont update for a login user

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

Please I need help with some custom rules configurations in Odoo 11.

Currently I'm doing a rule that allow an user only access to a certains product categories, for that I have a Many2many field which specify those categories:

```py
product_category_ids = fields.Many2many('product.category')
```

Here is the rule that only allows access to that categories:

```xml
<record model="ir.rule" id="product_template_category_users">
    <field name="name">product.template.category.users</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="product.model_product_template"/>
    <field name="perm_read" eval="True"/>
    <field name="perm_write" eval="True"/>
    <field name="perm_unlink" eval="True"/>
    <field name="perm_create" eval="True"/>
    <field name="domain_force">[('categ_id', 'child_of', user.product_category_ids.ids)]</field>
</record>
```

The rule works fine, but I have this problem:

- Login with user "A" who has that rule
- Login in another sesion with user "B" and update user "A"
  adding a new category to categories field
- Return with user "A" and the rule doesn't show the new category added, also reload page doesn't work.

The changes only apply in "A" user when I change the current company or reload the Odoo Service.

I think that it has to be something with the user storing data when the user login, maybe is some way to update that data and allow the rule to read it from "user". I need that the changes doing to users apply in real time to that connected users without have to change the current company or reload the Odoo service.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: It sounds like Odoo is caching this information. I wonder, do you have any options to change the cache parameters? Perhaps getting rid of the cache altogether?

Answer (score 0):

This is strange that it should work, but only after changing current company or restarting the Odoo server.

Can you try your modifications on a blank database and/or a new database with demo data loaded? If possible, it would be good to test this on an entirely different server to see if the problem might lay there.

Perhaps you can also try modifying your `force_domain` like this:

```
['|', ('categ_id', 'in', user.product_category_ids.ids), ('categ_id', 'child_of', user.product_category_ids.ids)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has the same problem, I solve it using this funcion every time i made a change in the product categories field of user

```
self.env['ir.rule'].clear_cache()
```

That code clear the cache of rules so the rules apply the new domain.

Answer (score 0):

Add `self.env['ir.rule'].clear_cache()` into `create()` and `write()` method of your model.